# How to push changes in package.json of kentico-cloud-delivery of node_modules into bitbucket

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket, node-modules, kentico-kontent

According to the Kentico technical support adviser, in order to get my create-react-app application rendered on IE11, I had to change the following line of code inside the node_modules -> kentico-cloud-delivery -> package.json file:

```
"main": "./_bundles/kentico-cloud-delivery-sdk.browser.umd.min.js"
```

After this change, my react application is rendering on my local IE, but the problem is that how can I push this change into the bitbucket so that the react application could be rendered on IE11 on a server as well.

Regarding that usually, we never push the node_modules into bitbucket and put it in .gitignore file, would you please let me know how can I resolve this problem.
Note: My project is a create-react-app application.

Comment: Could you describe more in detail what files are you pushing to the bitbucket? And how do you make a deployment from the bitbucket to the hosting?

Comment: You shouldn't change the package.json of your dependency. Since 'kentico-cloud-delivery-sdk.browser.umd.min.js' is pretty standard umd javascript, you can import it directly in react - instead of using 'import from 'kentico-cloud-delivery' you can impot directly from 'kentico-cloud-delivery/_bundles/_bundles/kentico-cloud-delivery-sdk.browser.umd.min'

Answer (score 1):

By not pushing your npm-modules to a bitbucket server it means that the application running there will fetch packages from a list in a file usually called package.json. So, you are probably pushing a .json file to a bitbucket which contains all dependency information and which you can edit to render your app in IE11.

Cheers!

Comment: It is NOT the general package.json which is usually located on the root of a project, it is the kentico-cloud-delivery package.json inside the node_modules, so I think I have to push it in Bitbucket, but I don't know how?

Comment: In that case, contact your seniors and tell them about your specific problem. The way I see it is you can either push your version of kentico-cloud-delivery or make a PR if it is open source.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to link [the issue](https://github.com/Kentico/kentico-cloud-js/issues/147) where the advised workaround is to set [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) load appropriate package and the [linked issue](https://github.com/Kentico/kentico-cloud-js/issues/69) for all the context.

The issue itself is caused because of [parse5](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5) library **does not publish ES5 code** to npm and therefore the build fails.

- So the root cause of this issue is the parse5 library.

## Possible solutions

1) **The general recommendation** from [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify) i**s to upgrade to v.2+** and this is quoted also on the [FAQ](https://github.com/Kentico/kentico-cloud-js/blob/17b41f36e00f3cfe7d2084825b914c3d6d1a46c4/packages/delivery/FAQ.md) section of Kentico Cloud javascript SDK.

2) If you want to place the workaround **despite all recommendations** because it is a manual change to the automatically managed `node_modules` you need to assure that the change of the package is preserved on the server before the build is made. So after `npm install`/`yarn` you would edit the package.json file in `node_modules`.

The script (named i.e. `workaround.js` written in node) would look like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const KCPackagePath = 'node_modules/kentico-cloud-delivery/package.json';
const package = require(KCPackagePath);

package.main = "./_bundles/kentico-cloud-delivery-sdk.browser.umd.min.js"

fs.writeFile(configPath, JSON.stringify(package, undefined, 2), function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error while writing to file: ' + KCPackagePath);
    throw err;;
  }
  console.info('Package was successfully updated.')
});
```

and define a script in `package.json` in your app from

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "workaround": "node workaround.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer to the question of how to ignore one file in the repository and ignore the rest in the folder is using `!` [pattern format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

```
node_modules
!node_modules/kentico-delivery-sdk/package.json
```

**!BUT!** `npm install`/`yarn` command would still replace the `package.json`content